# Calling C function only by name without arguments

Tags: c

I started working on this C project and I found this weird code that I have never seen any thing like !

```
cas_send_browser_event_cb(cas_browser_event_t ev, void* priv)
   {
      Function_code ...
   }
```

As you can see this function take two arguments , the first one is an `enum` and the second is `void *`.

I look for the call of this function and I find this :

```
casware_register_cb_uievent (cas_send_browser_event_cb , NULL);
```

As you can see, it is passed as a parameter to another function without arguments and even without `()`. I can't understand this code. Am I missing something ? (well it is somehow related to event programming).

Comment: it is passing a pointer to the function `cas_send_browser_event_cb`

Comment: It looks like `casware_register_cb_uievent` takes a pointer to a function of the same type that `cas_send_browser_event_cb` is, so the first argument to `casware...` decays to that pointer. The function will probably only be called later via its pointer.

Comment: first, mandatory, obvious step: check the defintion/declaration of `casware_register_cb_uievent`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`casware_register_cb_uievent (cas_send_browser_event_cb , NULL);`

is passing a pointer to the function `casware_register_cb_uievent`

To understand a little more consider the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>


void hello()
{
        printf("hello world");
}

void world(void (*fun)())
{
         fun();
}

main()
{
        world(hello);
}
```

Here the function `world` is similar to the function `casware_register_cb_uievent`

`void world(void (*fun)())` the function `world` accepts a pointer to a function which is pointed by  `fun`

now when the function `hello` (similar to the function `cas_send_browser_event_cb`) is given as input it is similar to assining the pointer as

`fun = hello`

the function call

`fun()` in `world` calls the function pointed by it, `hello` 
producing output as

`hello world`

when a function is declaread as

`void (*fun)();`
a function pointer is created.

The function pointer can be assigned using name of another function to which it is to be pointed

`fun = hello;`

now on calling the pointer, `fun` the function being pointed, `hello` is intern called

Answer (score 1):

It's a [function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) that's being passed, that's likely been [typedef](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/typedef.html)-ed. This means that the location of the `case_send_browser_event` is being passed, so that it can alter the behavior of the `casweare_register_cb_uievent` function.

This kind of passing is very helpful in algorithms where you'd want to maximize for different things on the fly, so changing the Boolean function used to do a compare from a minimize to a maximize would provide opposite behavior for a sort algorithm.